# Where is the github for ubuntu 18.04 (gnome) system monitor tool?

Tags: gnome, system-monitor, open-source

I notice the most recent copy right for it is 2011, is it no longer supported? I'm interested in learning from this tool. Does anyone know where it's opensource code is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pulled the trigger too soon. I just found it myself. It's [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-system-monitor/) if anyone else might need this in the future.